# Compact pieces of code which are doing similar things

Tags: javascript

While writing code in R I learned that whenever you repeat your code more than two times then a for loop is necessary. I am new in JavaScript and I am having exactly the same issue.

Three pieces of code doing similar thing and I am sure they can be compacted to a nice piece of code

The three pieces are :

```
    Bootstrapper.on('blur', '#application_id', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (~document.getElementById('application_id_error').innerHTML.indexOf('username exists')) {
                Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger('USA - username exists error');
        }
    }, 250);
    });
}

    Bootstrapper.on('blur', '#email_id', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (~document.getElementById('email_id_error').innerHTML.indexOf('email is already taken')) {
                Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger('USA - Username - Error');
        }
    }, 250);
    });
}



    Bootstrapper.on('blur', '#password', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (~document.getElementById('password_error').innerHTML.indexOf('password contains xyz')) {
                Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger('USA - Password - Error');
        }
    }, 250);
    });
}
```

***My (unsuccessful) effort to answer question 1***

```
var errorID = ['password', 'email', 'application_id'],
    errorMessage = ['password contains xyz', 'email is already taken', 'username exists'],
    eventName = ['username exists error', 'Username - Error', 'Password - Error']
i;

Bootstrapper.on('blur', '#password', '#email', '#application_id', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < errorID.length; i++) {
            if (~document.getElementById(errorID[[i]]).innerHTML.indexOf('errorMessage[[i]]')) {
                Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger('USA - ' + eventName[[i]]);
            }
        }

    }, 250);
});
}
```

**Question 1, how can I compact my code from 3 blocks to 1?**

**Question 2, Can I do || or & inside indexof()?  e.g `indexOf('xyz' || 'abc')`;**

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're actually asking? Is there anything wrong with your current effort?

Comment: thank you for your comment, I just laid out my questions more clearly.

Comment: regarding question 2, no. Inside an if you need to do `indexOf('xyz') || indexOf('abc')` (with whatever you're trying to find the index on). Also, `~` is bitwise negation. You want `!` for logical negation.

Comment: Also `indexOf('errorMessage[[i]]')` I'm pretty sure you meant `indexOf(errorMessage[i])` (no quotes and just one pair of brackets), otherwise you're looking for a string which spells out literally `"errorMessage[[i]]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var errorMessages = { 
        'password': 'password contains xyz',
        'email' : 'email is already taken',
        'application_id' :  'username exists'
}

var eventNames = { 
        'password': 'Password - Error',
        'email' : 'Username - Error',
        'application_id' :  'username exists error'
}


Bootstrapper.on('blur', '#password', '#email', '#application_id', function(event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var errorId = event.currentTarget.id + "_error";
            var errorMsg = errorMessages[event.currentTarget.id];

                if (~document.getElementById(errorId).innerHTML.indexOf(errorMsg)) {
                    Bootstrapper.ensEvent.trigger('USA - ' + eventNames[event.currentTarget.id]);
                }


        }, 250);
    });
```